# Integer pointers and the 'incompatible pointer type warning'

Tags: c, pointers, integer, warnings

I have read many of the replies to this problem but am not understanding it as it relates to my code so I must ask and hope for clarity.

The program is a magic square verifier for my midterm, and the code runs and outputs properly but I am getting warnings and so I want to clean it up before I submit it. There are actually two bits that give warnings but I am hoping that understanding the first one will help me clean up the second, since I want to understand not just paste an answer.

The code in question:

```
int ms[COLS][COLS] = 
{
{16,  3,  2, 13 },
{ 5, 10, 11,  8 },
{ 9,  6,  7, 12 },
{ 4, 15, 14,  1 }
}; 

const int* msPtr = ms;
```

I am trying to set up a constant integer pointer to the first element of my array, something I can pass on to functions so they can use but not modify my array values. I suspect that I am needing to either 'cast' something or have a syntax error here.

The warning is "[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type" referring to the "const int* msPtr = ms;" line above.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
const int * pointer_to_1st_int_of_ms = &ms[0][0];
```

Comment: So as I read that, it worked btw, I am making a pointer that is a constant integer with the value of the address at (&) ms [0][0].

Comment: The name is confusing; msPtr should be int**.

Comment: `&ms[0][0]` returns `int *`.

Comment: Thank you, I now get how that works and was able to get a pointer to the whole array working as well. I now have clean code and some deeper question for my professor!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
const int (* msPtr)[COLS] = ms;
```

Since ms is 2D array, so require 2D int pointer.

Comment: So is this casting msPtr? It didn't seem to work for me but I think I am going to use it for passing the entire array to a second function and see if that works.

Comment: Its a 2D pointer, so you need to use **msPtr to get value of particular index .

Comment: also correct, but it however isn't a pointer to the 1st `int` in the 2d-array, but to the 1st 1d-array in the 2d-array.

Comment: I was able to use your example to knock out what I think of as a pointer to the whole array `const int (*arPtr)[COLS][COLS] = &ms;` in any event I was able to get the output I expected from my function with `printSquare((*arPtr));`. Thank you.